# do you include the step before a comparison is made in the number of iterations a sorting algorithm takes?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, pseudocode, bubble-sort

Im having a  bit of a mind blank, as the question states; when you are counting the number of steps an algorithm takes to complete do you have to include a step where no comparisons have been made yet?

for example:

if you have a list: `5,3,7`

and you perform a bubble sort on it. It would;

1) compare `5` and `3` and swap them as `5>3`. The list is now `3,5,7`

2) compare `5` and `7` with no change as `5<7`. The list is now `3,5,7`

3) compare `3` and `5` with no change as expected. The list is still `3,5,7`

4) compare `5` and `7` with no change as expected. The list is still `3,5,7`

now would the number of iterations taken be 4 or 5? ... or have i got that completely wrong?

Thanks

Comment: For sorts, it is common to count the number of compares and the number of swaps (in place sorts) or moves (merge like sorts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sometimes helps to look at / think about the code: (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort))

```
procedure bubbleSort( A : list of sortable items )
   repeat     
     swapped = false
     for i = 1 to length(A) - 1 inclusive do:
       // this is the start of an iteration
       if A[i-1] > A[i] then
         swap( A[i-1], A[i] )
         swapped = true
       end if
       // this is the end of an iteration
     end for
   until not swapped
end procedure
```

Based on the above, it should be easy to see that we only count an iteration when we're actually doing a comparison.

So it would be 4 iterations.

---

As a technicality, you could also talk about iterations in terms of the `repeat ... until` loop, which would give you quite different results.

And the 'steps' can certainly be split up into a lot smaller parts.

For ambiguities similar to the above, we tend to stick to [big-O notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), which really just gives us a rate of growth of an algorithm's running time.

Answer (score 2):

You have performed 4 **iterations**. This is why number of **iterations** is 4.

```
Algorithm

//... some precondition steps

iteration( for... )  {       <
  //...                      < iteration steps
}                            <
```

Comment: **steps** and **iterations** are really different things

Comment: @quetzalcoatl in fact when you wrote "I truly can't fanthom how you got to a point that performing 4 steps is to be considered five.." you have counted iterations, so you use these notions exchangeably

Comment: No, I counted steps, with the typical meaning of **comparisons between elements**. 'Iterations' is a bogus, implementation-specific term that does not tell anything.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl can you provide some reasonable link to cover what you say please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm and try counting terms "step", "comparison" and "iteration".

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thanks, I've counted them, nothing about "iteration" there, also for OP this doesn't matter, IMHO you unnecessarily try to complicate things

Comment: Yes, you are completely right in that one. I've noticed that myself (i.e. I actually misread the question and initially thought he asks for step-count, not iteration-count) and that's why you currently have +2 with one from me ;))

Comment: @quetzalcoatl and you also have +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, at the point of time when no steps were performed yet, the step count = 0. After performing one step, the step count = 1. I truly can't fanthom how you got to a point that performing 4 steps is to be considered five..

Anyways, remember that it's usually analyzed as O(f(n)) where term not-related-to-N like +-constant i.e. +-1 or +-100 are simply dropped off.

Comment: ye i thought that would be the case, just had one of those blanks and thought i should check seeing as this was the first question asked in my coursework. Thanks